# Regex SQL BigQuery get number between '_'

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

Considering I have a table.

First one:

| user_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | OFF472_100_012_280421 |
| 1 | PPUU321_010_012_280421 |
| 2 | HHTUE_011_012_280421 |
| 2 | VENT471_012_012_280421 |

And I want to extract first number between two '_' in name column

The desirable table should looks like this

| user_id | name | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | OFF472_100_012_324504 | 100 |
| 1 | PPUU321_010_012_345625 | 10 |
| 2 | HHTUE_011_012_345345 | 11 |
| 2 | VENT471_012_012_345567 | 12 |

Help me please with sql query!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `split` and `offset`:

```
select *, CAST(split(name, '_')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64) as number
from mytable
```

Comment: @Smasell . . . This doesn't extract. the first number (as your question asks), this extracts the second component.  In fact, this will return an error if the second component is not a number.

Answer (score 1):

Using `REGEXP_EXTRACT` with a capture group:

```sql
SELECT user_id, name, REGEXP_EXTRACT(name, r'^[^_]+_0*(\d+)')
FROM yourTable;
```

Note: It appears that you want to also strip off any leading zeroes, so I have done this.  If you want to retain all digits, then use `^[^_]+_(\d+)`.